# Is an Android app still 64bit if i have a 32bit native libary?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, 64-bit, native

I have a native library i want to use, it offers the following binaries:

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86_64

Our minSDK is 18 if this is relevant.
According to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html armeabi, mips and mips64 are deprecated/removed.

What would be the best way to use it?

- Just use them all (increases apk from 6mb to 30mb)
- Use only armeabi and x86 (is the app still considered 64bit then?)
- Split the build (e.g.https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/)

Comment: *Use only armeabi and x86 (is the app still considered 64bit then?)* - No the app will be 32bit, 64 bit CPUs are compatible with 32 bit code

Answer (score 1):

x86_64 and arm64 can run without problem x86 and armeabi-v7a code, so if you don't include binaries for 64bit archs - 32bit binaries will be selected

So, if your goal isn't minimize apk size, you should include binaries for all targeted ABIs

Comment: Also x86 can run armeabi-v7a well though Intel Houdini, so in some cases just armeabi-v7a is enough (there is almost no x86 device on the market right now)

Answer (score 1):

Google has recently [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) that

> In August 2019, Play will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions.

So, you have a year and a half to get ready with arm64-v8a. At any rate, split APK is not hard, and is very handy.

I agree with @Anton Malyshev that most developers can ignore x86 targets in production (they may be very useful during development, because x86_64 emulator is much faster).